Suspend mode doesn´t work after updating ubuntu to 24.04
I upgraded Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.4, now the suspend mode doesn´t work. I ran the following command:
journalctl -b | grep -i suspend

and I got this:

oct 31 21:18:26 lvazdela-Aspire-E5-551 kernel: x86/pm: family 0x15 cpu
detected, MSR saving is needed during suspending.

I'm using an Aspire E15 laptop with an amd quad-core processor a10-7300
I found this question in
Ubuntu 24.04 suspend not work on Acer Aspire 5
but the suggested solution did'n work.
What can I do to solve the problem?
Thanks.

The next day I posted this question, I updated the OS, that solved the problem. Now the version of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS allows the suspend mode
